# Why does DIBS say "No paytype(s)! Missing test parameter?"

Tags: virtuemart, dibs

I'm not sure if this has started happening recently, but when using [DIBS Payment Services](http://www.dibspayment.com/) from Joomla 1.5 with VirtueMart 1.1.9, DIBS always say "No paytype(s)! Missing test parameter?" when *not* in test mode. It doesn't matter if we specify paytypes or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[DIBS' own FAQ](http://tech.dibs.dk/faq/) says:

> This error message is typically caused by two different issues:
>
> 1. Your merchant is in test mode at DIBS but transactions is being sent to DIBS without the test parameter http://tech.dibs.dk/10_step_guide/your_own_test/
> 2. Your merchant is not in test mode at DIBS, but transactions are being sent to DIBS with the test parameter.